# Class conflict: two jar files with the same classes

Tags: java, jvm, classpath, package

I have two jar files with similar Util class names, but different method signatures.

In jar1, I have a main method which must use the method in Util class in jar1. The JVM is linking to Util class in jar2.

How to resolve this class conflict?

Comment: normally one avoid sthat situation by using appropriate package names, such that they are different

Comment: How did you import these class?

Comment: I am using this solution. Thanks @AlexWien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally one avoids that situation by using appropriate package names, such that they are different.

In extreme situations, where you dont have the choice to change the jar files, 
there is the option "bootclasspath" where you can specify classes that gets loaded first.

Comment: It is possible to write your custom class loader that throws an Exception if for a given name there are more than one candidate?

Comment: Everything is possible. But this seems to be an overkill for most applications. You also can use an obfuscator, like ProGuard, that warns when duplicate classs definitions are found. Further one can set "treat warnings as errors", so then even the build would fail, if th eobfuscator is part of the ebuild

Comment: That would enforce the good pattern of choosing the names to be unique within a namespace (in this case the package). I was thinking on that... In that case, your application will never run if there is no unique name+package for a class. I will try to implement it. If you got any advise, more than welcome will be!.

Comment: package with class name should be unique. nothing more. so com.company.app.MyClass. The so called full qualified name

Comment: MMMM i don't get it. The Original poster, me, you, everybody here has experiencing from time to time this problem due to lack of imagination to figure out new names.

Comment: just make sure the package name is worldwide unique, Then it is no problem if there are hundred of different "Point" classes or "Data" or "Event". I never have run into this problem, only once when I have added two different version of the same library (e.g Log4j), which is another problem when this happens

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing. Hope to share more experiences like this. Nice to chat.

Comment: this is like emergecny medicine. you should try to heal the cause,

Comment: mmmmm... i am 50% agree with what you say. It could come in handy.

Comment: Update: Java 11+ no longer allow conflicts in the namespaces on the classpath.  You must identify and remove the bad dependency.

Answer (score 3):

If both jar files are loaded into the same classloader then there is no way to determine which class will get loaded. The only way to handle this is to isolate them so only one of them is loaded into the classloader you are using.

You can set up a classloader and only load the jar you want to get the class from, but it is probably much easier to just make sure classes are unique on your path.